# How do obj file faces work

Tags: obj

Specifically, I have a faces specified 'f v1/vt1 ... etc '. I understand that there are 3 vertices specified with respective texture coordinates, but how do those 3 textures end up being rendered onto a triangular face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have 3 textures per face but 3 points on one texture. Connecting them with lines you'll get a triangle on your texture, and this is the exact part that will be used on your face when rendered.

You may look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532670/1479630) answer.